# PHP: Foreach scoring help

Tags: php

I have this php that scores a test based on hourly answers:

```
    $score_a = 0;

    foreach(array(4,5,10) as $a){
        if ($a >= 2 && $a <= 4) {
            $score_a += 1;
        } else if ($a > 4 && $a <= 8) {
            $score_a += 3;
        } else if ($a > 8) {
            $score_a += 0;
        }
    };
```

I need the final "else if" to score a bit differently.  Instead of adding .5 once if the value is >8, I need it to add .5 for each whole number above 8.

So this score needs to be 5 and not 4.5.

Comment: not clear if you can explain it more thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you need to do?

Comment: I dont' get it. What do you expect the outcome of 4,5 and 10 each to be? And what is the initial value of $score_a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like: `$score_a += floor($a - 8) * .5;` ?

You can use it like so:

```
foreach(array(4,5,10) as $a){
    if ($a >= 2 && $a <= 4) {
        $score_a += 1;
    } else if ($a > 4 && $a <= 8) {
        $score_a += 3;
    } else if ($a > 8) {
        $score_a += floor($a - 8) * .5;
    }
};
```

Comment: I think so?  I'm a major beginner...

Basically, for each number above 8, .5 needs to be added (unlike the previous, which are single additions).

Comment: Will test tomorrow.  It's 4 AM here... :)

Comment: elseif ( $a >= 9 ) { //K Prime's code goes here }

must work.